# How to dynamically print the raw value of the input with AutoNumeric js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help on AutoNumeric js.

I use input and span this way:

```
<input type="text" name="currency" id="currency">
<span class="value_currency"></span>
```

I'm using AutoNumeric in javascript like this:

```
new AutoNumeric('#currency', 'Turkish');
```

And output as follows:

```
1.750,15
```

I need this:

```
1750.15
```

My question is, how do I dynamically print in value_currency when the data in the currency changes. But I need raw values not formatted value. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code below uses jquery to track when a change is made to the `#currency` input, I have used broad event triggers so that the code runs on any `keydown`, `paste`, etc change. You may want to tweak these to your needs (i.e. reduce the number of triggers). After registering a trigger event the code does the following:

1. Gathers the `.val()` of the input as s tring
2. Replaces all characters that are not numeric or a decimal point (i.e. your currency characters) with `.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')`
3. Assigns this new condensed string to the `.html()` of `.currency-value`.

> If you would like commas to remain within the string (i.e. £1,234.56 being simplified to 1,234.56 then change the `regex` function from `.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')` to `.replace(/[^\d.,-]/g, '')` (i.e. add a comma within it). The code below currently removes commas.

Let me know if this isn't what you wanted.

---

## Basic Demo (Turkish)

**Turkish Lira was added to v4.2.8.** This is a basic setup, demonstrating how you can get the raw value just for comma based currencies.

```js
// Apply Autonumeric to #currency input
new AutoNumeric('#currency', 'Turkish');

// Trigger function of any change to #currency input 
$("#currency").on("propertychange change keyup paste input", function(){

  // Get value from input, replace all non-numeric or '.' values 
  rawValue = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d,-]/g, '');
  
  // Replace comma with decimal point
  rawValue = rawValue.replace(",", '.');

  // Print value
  $(".value_currency").html( rawValue );
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/autonumeric@4.5.1/dist/autoNumeric.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="currency" id="currency">
<span class="value_currency"></span>
```

---

## Extended Demo

This extended demo allows you to use an `attr` to store the currency type and also whether it is comma or decimal point based.

```js
// Apply Autonumeric to #currency input
$("input[currency]").each(function() {

  // Get id of this element
  currencyID = $(this).attr("id");

  // Apply AutoNumeric to given input
  new AutoNumeric('#' + currencyID, $(this).attr("currency"));

});


// Trigger function of any change to #currency input 
$("input[currency]").on("propertychange change keyup paste input lostfocus", function() {

  // Get divider from the element's attribute
  divider = $(this).attr("currency-divider");

  // Create regex expression and apply
  var regex2 = new RegExp('[^0-9' + divider + ']', 'g');
  rawValue = $(this).val().replace(regex2, '');

  // Decimalisation of non-decimal based currencies by default if only a single divider is specified
  // Automatically applied to comma based currencies only
  if (divider.length == 1 && divider != ".") {
    rawValue = rawValue.replace(divider, '.');
  }

  // Print raw value
  $(this).parent().children(".value_currency").html(rawValue);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/autonumeric@4.5.1/dist/autoNumeric.min.js"></script>

<p><strong>Automatic decimalisation</strong> is applied if there is only a single character divider added to input. </p>
<p>Attributes needed in the inputs include:<p>
<ul>
  <li>currency - i.e. 'British', 'Turkish'</li>
  <li>currency-divider - i.e. '.' or ',' or ',.'</li>
</ul>

<hr>

<div class="currency-wrapper">

  <label>Turkish ₺</label>

  <input type="text" name="currency" id="currencyTurkish" currency-divider="," currency="Turkish">
  <span class="value_currency"></span>

</div>

<hr>


<div class="currency-wrapper">

  <label>Turkish ₺ (divider set as comma and decimal)</label>
  <input type="text" name="currency" id="currencyTurkishDouble" currency-divider=".," currency="Turkish">
  <span class="value_currency"></span>

</div>

<hr>

<div class="currency-wrapper">

  <label>British £</label>
  <input type="text" name="currency" id="currencyBritish" currency-divider="." currency="British">
  <span class="value_currency"></span>

</div>

<hr>

<div class="currency-wrapper">

  <label>British £ (no divider set)</label>
  <input type="text" name="currency" id="currencyBritishNoDivider" currency-divider="" currency="British">
  <span class="value_currency"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer it worked but i made a mistake. Its not british currency, it is turkish currency. British and turkish currency are different. I edit my question please check.

Comment: Updated - got two demos, you likely only need the basic demo.

Comment: It worked for me, thank you for your helps. Cheers !

Answer (score 5):

In case it's of help to anyone, I ended up using AutoNumeric static method 'getNumber'

https://docs.autonumeric.org/Documentation/static%20methods/

In this case:

```
AutoNumeric.getNumber('#currency');
```